# Why dont netty logs show proper class and package information

Tags: java, log4j, netty, slf4j

I use SLF4J in my [game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) project which uses Slf4j and Log4j. However netty specific logs come out like below.

```
2013-06-08 13:37:30,254 [Slf4JLogger.java:71][DEBUG]:Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2013-06-08 13:37:30,261 [Slf4JLogger.java:71][DEBUG]:Platform: Windows
2013-06-08 13:37:30,270 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:Java version: 7
2013-06-08 13:37:30,273 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner: available
2013-06-08 13:37:30,274 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:java.nio.Buffer.address: available
2013-06-08 13:37:30,274 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
2013-06-08 13:37:30,275 [Slf4JLogger.java:71][DEBUG]:sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
2013-06-08 13:37:30,276 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
2013-06-08 13:37:30,276 [Slf4JLogger.java:76][DEBUG]:sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2013-06-08 13:37:30,278 [Slf4JLogger.java:71][DEBUG]:Javassist: unavailable
```

They dont show the actual netty class and package information. My corresponding Log4j pattern is:

```
log4j.appender.toLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%F:%L][%p]:%m%n
```

What am I configuring wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `%c` instead of `%F` in your pattern. `%F` - Outputs the file name where the logging request was issued and `%c` prints logger name. In Netty all logging goes through the wrapper classes in your case it's Slf4JLogger.class

Your pattern should look like:

log4j.appender.toLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [**%c**:%L][%p]:%m%n

EDIT due to comment:

Yes there is a way to print only filename:

```
%c{1}
```

See documentation:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns

Comment: This worked, but is there a way to only print out the file name? Now it prints the whole package like so -> io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0:76 while I just require PlatformDpeendent0:76